# Show that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{1/n}_{n+1} = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{1/n}_n$ without using logarithms.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that for any power series, the radius of convergence of the derivative equals the radius of convergence of the original power series.
My proof is conditional on the following fact:

Let $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=0}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers, such that $$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{1/n}_n < \infty$$
Then $$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{1/n}_{n+1} = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{1/n}_n$$

I am stuck on how to prove this. I looked elsewhere on stackexchange, but all the ideas I found seem to be using logarithms. I can't do that, since logarithms are only later defined through power series, so I might run into circularities.

Any pointers in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:

Let $L = \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|x_n|}$ and pick some integer $k$. The following
shows that $L = \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|x_{n+k}|}$.

Suppose $L \in (0,\infty)$. Pick $\epsilon>0$ then there is some $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we have $\sqrt[n]{|x_n|} \le (L+\epsilon)$ and there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\sqrt[n]{|x_n|} \ge (L-\epsilon)$.

The above statements are equivalent to $|x_n| \le (L+\epsilon)^n$ for $n \ge N$, and $|x_n| \ge (L-\epsilon)^n$ infinitely often.

Then for $n \ge N-k$, we have $|x_{n+k}| \le (L+\epsilon)^{n+k} $ and
$|x_{n+k} | \ge (L-\epsilon)^{n+k}$ infinitely often.

Equivalently, we have $\sqrt[n]{|x_n|} \le (L+\epsilon)^{1+{k \over n}}$ for $n \ge N-k$ and $\sqrt[n]{|x_n|} \ge  (L-\epsilon)^{1 + {k \over n}}$ infinitely often.

Since $\lim_n (L+\epsilon)^{1+{k \over n}} = L+\epsilon$ and
$\lim_n (L-\epsilon)^{1 + {k \over n}}= L-\epsilon$, we see that for some $N' \ge N$ we have
$\sqrt[n]{|x_{n+k}|} \le (L+2\epsilon)$ for $n \ge N'$ and $\sqrt[n]{|x_{n+k}|} \ge  (L-2\epsilon)$ infinitely often.

In particular, $\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|x_{n+k}|} = L$.

The cases $L=0$, $L=\infty$ are handled in a similar manner (only one of the two inequalities above need to be proved).

Answer (score 2):

Set $x_n = a_n^{1/n}$ and $y_n = a_{n+1}^{1/n+1}$. Then $y_n^{n+1/n} = y_n y_n^{1/n} \overset{\text{def}}{=}z_n$. We are asked to show the larget subsequential limit of $z_n$ agrees with the largest subsequential limit of $x_n$. It is clear that $\limsup z_n = \lim_k y_{n_k}y_{n_k}^{1/n_k}$. On the other hand, $\lim_k y_{n_k} = \lim_k x_{n_k} = \limsup x_n$. Since $\lim_k y_{n_k}^{1/n_k} = 1$, the thesis follows.

Addendum: There is an error in the proof, at the last step. It is possible for $\lim_k y_{n_k}^{1/n_k} = 0$. This is easily resolved, so I will leave it as is.